# Replacement for Office Web Components

Tags: asp.net, windows

I have some ASP.Net pages that use Office Web Components.  I've recently read that the Office Web Components do not work on Windows 7.

Is this true?

If so, what can I use to replace the spreadsheet functionality?

Comment: Where did you read this? Do you have a link?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The Pivot Table and Spreadsheet web components do not function on Windows 7.", mentions as source http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2067463

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 ships with the providers of MSOLAP.2 and MSOLAP.4 but not MSOLAP.3 which is needed for SSAS 2005 cubes.  You can just install the 64 bit provider and OWC will work in windows 7.

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services 9.0 OLE DB Provider 
The Analysis Services 9.0 OLE DB Provider is a COM component that software developers can use to create client-side applications that browse metadata and query data stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services. This provider implements both the OLE DB specification and the specification’s extensions for online analytical processing (OLAP) and data mining.

Dowloand here
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15748